solscan doesn't display details of newly deployed program
new to solana.
I deployed testing program on devnet and I can see the details on explorer
https://explorer.solana.com/address/GPM29Ve5KtpkKjuBjyiyvigttfv5ytZfBH3LrDM9NtDa?cluster=devnet
however, if I check it on solscan, it doesn't seem to find it.
https://solscan.io/account/GPM29Ve5KtpkKjuBjyiyvigttfv5ytZfBH3LrDM9NtDa?cluster=devnet
this is quite confusing. any help would be appreciated.

Solscan devnet API's aren't the best.
The Solana explorer and Solana FM are your best bet when developing https://solana.fm/address/GPM29Ve5KtpkKjuBjyiyvigttfv5ytZfBH3LrDM9NtDa/transactions?cluster=devnet-alpha
